# How to use imagemin to compress images and busboy

Tags: node.js, imagemin

I want to use the following library to compress images
https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin

The problem is when the user uploads using a form, how do I plug in the file details from the form to the image min plugin? Like for example, if the file form field is call example-image, how do I plug that file form field to image min plugin so that it can compress the images?

I tried:

req is from the express/nodejs req

```
  var filebus = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers }),
   promises = [];

    filebus.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, contentType) {

        var fileBuffer = new Buffer(0),
            s3ImgPath;

        if (file) {
            file.on('data', function (d) {
                fileBuffer = Buffer.concat([fileBuffer, d]);
            }).on('end', function () {
                Imagemin.buffer(fileBuffer, {
                    plugins: [
                        imageminMozjpeg(),
                        imageminPngquant({quality: '80'})
                    ]
                }).then(function (data) {
                    console.log(data[0]);
                    if (s3ImgPath) {
                        promises.push(this.pushImageToS3(s3ImgPath, data[0].data, contentType));
                    }
                });
            }.bind(this));
        }
    });
```

But the problem is I rather have a buffer of the file that I can upload to S3. I don't want to come the files to a build/images folder. I want to get a buffer for the file, compress it, and upload that buffer to s3. How can I use image min to get a buffer of the file upload via html form and upload that to s3?

Comment: Please show any code you have so far. Preferably a working server and an webpage with a form.

Comment: I added more info

Comment: Use it - https://www.npmjs.com/package/compress-images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for the output parameter shows that it is optional (though admittedly, the function declaration did not, which might be confusing).

> output
>
> Type: string
>
> Set the destination folder to where your files will be written. If no
>   destination is specified no files will be written.

Therefore, you can opt out of writing the files to storage and just use the output in memory:

```
imagemin([file.path], {
  plugins: [
      imageminMozjpeg(),
      imageminPngquant({quality: '65-80'})
  ]
}).then(files => {
  // upload file to S3
});
```

Comment: how do we use that with busboy? do you know? See the code above